# rewrite multiple php query with .htaccess parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, parameters

**site**.com/**info**rmation.php?country=**usa**&state=**co**&city=**denver**

to

**site**.com/**info**/**usa**/**co**/**denver**

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^info/([^/]+)/(.*)$/(.*)$ information.php?country=$1&state=$2&city=$3   [L]
RewriteRule ^info/([^/]+)/(.*)$ information.php?country=$1&state=$2                 [L]
RewriteRule ^info/([^/]+) informationl.php?country=$1                               [L]
```

**information.php**

```
<?php
echo $_GET["country"].'<br>';
echo $_GET["state"].'<br>';
echo $_GET["city"].'<br>';
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']'<br>';
?>
```

The first two query works fine but it wont catch the third one, 
well it does but it attach it to the 2nd query

usa

co/denver

country=usa&state=co/denver

I think im missing something, can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two `$`'s in there. This symbol means "end of the match", so you're "city" parameter is getting gobbled up by the "state" one. Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^info/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ information.php?country=$1&state=$2&city=$3   [L]
RewriteRule ^info/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ information.php?country=$1&state=$2                 [L]
RewriteRule ^info/([^/]+) informationl.php?country=$1                               [L]
```